# How do I know when a group of accidentals lead to a key change or not?

Tags: analysis, key-signatures, accidentals, modulation

Especially for something like this

[image: Excerpt with F naturals and G sharps from a D major piece]

(which is originally in D Major), how do I know that it doesn't constitute a key change? A more general question would probably be how do I identify key changes in sheet music in general?

Answer (score 1):

For your particular example, there is no clear way of telling, because it lacks context. In general, the key has changed when music feels more or less "at home" in a key different than the previous one. For this to happen, the new key has to be properly established, and music has to remain in this new key for some time. Therefore it depends on what there is before and after. In any case, the concept of key change (modulation) is kind of a theoretical simplification; in practise, analysis of a musical score is not always white or black.

This is a complex topic, that involves understanding well the concept of Key, function of different chords, etc… If you want to get it right, study a good harmony text. I strongly recommend you Arnold Schönberg's Harmony book. Chapter 9 talks about modulation, but reading previous chapters might also be usefu/needed.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

To detect a modulation based on the presence of accidentals requires recognizing whether those accidentals — plus any unchanged members of the key signature — themselves could constitute a new key (or shift between major and minor).

## General answer: considerations upon seeing accidentals

Accidentals show up in three common situations:

1. *The leading tone in a minor key.* Recognizing this situation comes down to knowing which pitch is the leading tone and noting that it's the only prominent accidental. Beyond just the leading tone, one would also look to notice how scale degree 6 is or is not altered.
2. *Chromatic alterations.* These can look more like a key change, but are generally recognizable either by being very short-lived or by not being joined by other accidentals necessary for a particular key. A piece in C major in which some E#s and F#s appear, is probably not modulating to F# major. If it were, we could reasonably expect to see some G#s and A#s, for example.
3. *Modulation.* In this case, we'd expect clusters of accidentals sufficient to suggest a new key (signature). Starting of in C major, but then suddenly seeing a lot of F#s, C#s, and G#s in close proximity (without being immediately cancelled by naturals) would clearly suggest a passage in A major. And an additional E# or two would suggest F# minor.

## Excerpt analysis

In the given excerpt, the F naturals (in the 2nd through 7th measures) suggest a shift to D minor, C major, or A minor. In the C major case, though, we'd expect to see some prominent C naturals; and in the A minor case, not only would C natural be expected, but so would some G#s, to reinforce the shift in tonal center. However, the F naturals are consistent enough to at least keep our ears open for D minor. The absence of Bbs argues against a "real" modulation, however.

The introduction of G# (8th measure) might raise an eyebrow, but since it's immediately followed by G natural, it's reasonable to view it as a momentary chromatic pitch.

Seeing both F# and G# at the end of the line is at least suggestive that we could be heading toward A major, but one must keep an open mind, because they're also clearly part of a melodic chromatic scale (E-F-F#-G-G#), and we need to know what's happening beyond the given excerpt to know where we're actually headed. Is it "just" a chromatic scale, or is it leading beyond A major to, say, E major (that is, is there a D# lying just over the horizon)?

## And beyond just the accidentals

Taking a step beyond the question of analyzing just the accidentals themselves, the presence of a cadence is a core analytical insight as to whether the accidental is a brief alteration or indicative of a key change.

The excerpt opens with an A major chord followed by the D minor, which suggests at least a temporary focus on D minor, if not a full-on modulation. On the other hand, the later accidentals do not participate in cadential sequences (short of know the next measure after the excerpt), so are more likely of a more ornamental nature.

Comment: I like this answer best, and I also wonder if there’s a benefit in looking for cadences to confirm modulation or not. At least in baroque and classical music before Beethoven, I would be reluctant to call anything a key change without an authentic or plagal cadence in the new key, although a half cadence in the right context might do it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Absolutely. Added a small section to the post. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

The composer starts in D major, as you say, but temporarily wants to put some D minor flavour in. As it's only on a temporary basis, and he's returning to D major, it's a modulation rather than a key change. So it's easier for everyone if the key signature stays the same, and accidentals are used to signify changed notes.

A proper key change would involve two naturals, at the beginning of the new key, often with a double bar line, and the new key signature put in place. If the new key is C/Am, it looks a little odd, as there would be the naturals, followed by seemingly no key signature.A look at the next few notes should give sufficient clues, though.

Comment: Is it in some flavor of non-American English that “modulation” doesn’t mean a key change?

Comment: @ToddWilcox In fact, Tim asked that very question a couple years later: [What's the exact difference between modulation, key change and tonicisation?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/74379/70803). Good question with good answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

There are modulations, and there are key changes.  When a piece includes a "development" section, harmonic excursions will generally use accidentals.  When it's more of a set of variations, each may get its own key signature.  Or a composer may change key signature for purely pragmatic reasons, to make a section easier to read.   The ultimate Key Change is the "up a semitone for the last chorus" device, common in popular music.  This will definitely get a new key signature!

Is the Ring Cycle a series of modulations - it begins in Eb and also ends there, several evenings later - or are there key changes?   Does Bach's 'Minuet in G' modulate to D, or change key?  Would we be dissatisfied if the Ring didn't "come home"?  What about the Bach?    Do you find the unresolved modulation in "Unforgettable" magical, or vaguely unsatisfying?

You wanted an answer and I'm just offering more questions :-)  Questions on how to label something often end up like that.

Comment: Another question - where exactly does Unforgettable modulate?

Comment: Nat King Cole sings it in F.  The song takes some pleasing harmonic detours but remains firmly rooted in F until the final four bars when it settles on a definite Bb, the subdominant key. 
It's odd, and to my ears rather unsatisfactory.   Works best when the refrain's sung just once, as on the YouTube clip of Nat's TV show.  The duet version with Natalie goes back for a second try, and has to jump through some harmonic hoops  - a half-chorus instrumental in Db then a rather contrived slip back into F for the ending.
Great melody, but structural problems that I find hard to spin into virtues.

Comment: Written in, well, the jury seems to be out! I have dots with a G major key sig., but others with a C major key sig. The duet may be like that as it was done post mortem, so there may only have been certain recordings of Nat to use. The original song sounds o.k. to me, with no perceivable modulation. For secong time around, I usually play a bar of the V of the original 1st chord, which makes it sound as if there's a key change there.

Comment: All of Nat's contributions to the duo recording are in F.   The inherent modulation in the basic song may not worry you, but I'm surprised you don't perceive it.

Answer (score 0):

There are four big categories:

- Change in key signature: a new key signature is inserted within the score. This is when a whole section is in a new key, you see it a lot, for example, in the middle, or "trio", section of ternary forms.
- Modulation: accidentals in the score including a proper cadence of some kind in the new key, of fairly long duration, something like a full phrase or more, basically you want to hear a phrase in a new key.
- Tonicization: accidental in the score "hinting" at a different tonic, brief duration, usually only long enough for a two chord change, not proper phrase ending cadence as with a modulation. One place to look for this is *sequential* passages.
- Change of mode: tonic stays the same, but modal degrees change, notable the third and sixth degrees of the scale.

Regarding your example, the harmony is entirely using chord roots `A` and `D`, and it mostly uses accidentals for a *mode change.* The key signature is for `D` major, but in second bar of the excerpt naturals are used to lower the `F#` to plain `F`, `F` natural being the minor third degree of the key `D` minor. When the tonic says the same, but it just changes from major to minor, that's a mode change.

Toward the end there is a pedal on `A` and above it there is an alternation of `G` natural and `G#`, this movement can be called "standing on the dominant", something very important in classical music. It's *intentionally* vacillating back and forth between the `G` natural which would be diatonic to `D` minor and the `G#` which would tonicize `A`, but it doesn't really set up `A` as the tonic. Again, that ambiguity is *intentional*. It's a way to set up tension. We don't see how it continues in the excerpt, but it probably goes to `D` something, major or minor, which would relieve the tension of playing around with the `G` natural and `G#` sharp.