# Is this chord bV° or something else?

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

I don't know much about music theory so I need some explanation!

While playing a tune, I came across this:
(in F minor) Bbm / Bdim7 / C7 / Fmin

Where is that Bdim7 coming from? Would I call it a bV° or something else?
And why is this working in that context (the Bdim7 being the vii° of C, I imagine that's why it lead well into it here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Music.SE!

This is what we call an *applied chord* (some also call it a *secondary chord*). And your guess is exactly correct: this is a chord that functions to briefly make another chord sound like tonic.

This B°7 is the °7 chord built on the leading tone (scale-degree 7) of C major. Since this B°7 exists in C and not in F, playing it makes the music briefly sound like it's in the key of C. We call this act *tonicization*. You may have heard of *modulation*—a complete, lengthy move to another key—but a tonicization is a more brief move to another key. Think of modulation as jumping into the pool, but tonicization is just dipping your toe in. (See also [What's the exact difference between modulation, key change and tonicisation?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/74379/whats-the-exact-difference-between-modulation-key-change-and-tonicisation))

Since this B°7 chord is functioning to make C seem like a temporary tonic, we want to label the chord to show that function. As such, instead of labeling this ♭V°7, it's better understood as `vii°7/V`, showing that it is the vii°7 chord of V (C) in the overall key of F.

As such, your entire progression is best understood as i–iv–vii°7/V–V7–i.

While this chord is called a *secondary leading-tone chord*, there are other types of secondary (or applied) chords. The *secondary dominant* is probably the most common, and that's where you use the temporary tonic's V(7). Trying replacing that B°7 with a G7 to hear what a V7/V sounds like!

Comment: I knew about secondary dominants, but not of those other types of applied chords. I need to study all that, sound fun and interesting! 
thank you for your answer, I think the concept and use of that °7 herre is clear in my mind now!